# PostgreSQL "cannot REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW because it is being used by active queries in this session"

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I have a table of informations with a materialized view containing the permissions to it.  There is a trigger after INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE on the informations table to refresh the materialized view.

```
CREATE TABLE informations (
  id numeric PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(200)
);

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW informationspermissions AS (
  -- Insert business logic, references other tables here, irrelevant
  -- outputs unique pairs of (id, user)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX informationspermissions_id_user
ON informationspermissions
USING btree("id", "user");

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION refresh_informations()
RETURNS TRIGGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW CONCURRENTLY informationspermissions;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_refresh_informations AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
ON informations
FOR EACH STATEMENT EXECUTE PROCEDURE refresh_informations();
```

I have an update query where I am referencing the materialized view to make sure the user performing the update can actually access the information:

```
UPDATE informations
SET name='new name'
WHERE id=123 AND id IN (SELECT id FROM informationspermissions WHERE user=<user ID>);
```

Now, the problem is that I get hit with the following error:

```
cannot REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW "informationspermissions" because it is being used by active queries in this session
```

I have tried making the refresh concurrent or not, the `WITH DATA` flag, to no avail.  What are my options to make this work?  Is there any way to have the trigger run once the WHERE clause on the query has been resolved fully?

Comment: No, that won't work. You have to do something else. Refreshing the whole materialized view whenever something in the underlying tables changes is usually a bad idea (performance).

Comment: Your subquery is blocking the refresh

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe so what would be a better alternative?  The tables underlying `informationspermissions` are rarely updated, but read from very often, so it seemed reasonable to me perf-wise.

Comment: @FrankHeikens is there anything I can do to not make it block ?

Comment: If you want to keep your current design, split the `UPDATE` in two statements: the first queries the materialized view, the second updates `informations` without a subquery.

Comment: Why do you need a materialized view? We do use them sometimes, but only for precomputing aggregates on large amounts of data. When your underlying query is fast enough, you don't need a mat view and that would make your database simpler.

Comment: @FrankHeikens that's the issue, the underlying query behind `informationspermissions` is not that fast, so I'm trying to keep the number of times it gets recomputed to a strict minimum.

Comment: When it's not fast enough, the question is Why? And can it be improved to an acceptable/useful performance? Check the query plan using `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for this statement